# Why do i get lots of remote: when pushing to master

Tags: github

Lots of remote: when doing a git push origin master (this hasn't happened to me in 12 months of using git so i'm not sure whats happened here)

if you look in codeblock below there are 12+ remote:

```cs
$ git push origin master
Enumerating objects: 41, done.
Counting objects: 100% (41/41), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (19/19), done.
Writing objects: 100% (21/21), 1.73 KiB | 589.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 21 (delta 16), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote:                                                                          remote:                                                                         remote:                                                                         remote:                                                                         remote:                                                                         remote:                                                                         remote:                                                                         remote:                                                                         remote:                                                                         remote:                                                                         remote:                                                                         remote:                                                                         remote:                                                                         remote:                                                                         remote:                                                                         remote:                                                                         remote:                                                                         remote:                                                                         remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (16/16), completed with 16 local objects.
To https://github.com/xxx/xx.git
xxx master > master
```

Comment: Yeah snap. I'm seeing the same thing when pushing.

Comment: There was a GitHub incident earlier; might have been due to that https://www.githubstatus.com/incidents/nt6n1hs8bk3v Can you check if you're getting the same even now?

Comment: You are correct, not happening today. Looks like it was related to that i guess :) Thank you both for your time :)